# after upgrade to new PHP cron jobs stopped working

Tags: php, cron

Last year I purchased an encrypted script which runs two cron jobs, a month ago the crons stop working and I have talk to the hosting company they said its script problem. The PHP cron file works fine without any errors when visited by browser, the script provider told me that this issue should be fixed by hosting service and refuse to help!

here is the command used it run every 10 minutes:

```
/home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php
```

cPanel Version  64.0 (build 24)
Apache Version  2.4.25
PHP Version     5.6.30

My question is it true upgrading the PHP version will affect cron job and how can I solve this?

Comment: can you run them from the command line?

Comment: What did you upgrade from and to? Upgrading PHP won't affect the system CRON, what it executes `php /file.php` might have a different result though (e.g. using `mysql_` from 5.6 -> 7). You should have the company provide you with the decrypted script, or tell you what version you need to be running (I personally wouldn't pay for an encrypted script).

Comment: the upgrade was not too lagre its  from version 5.4 to 5.6.30 ,the script provider ask for a big money for his help!

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, upgrading PHP *can* effect your scripts -- the crons aren't run by Apache or PHP; the crons run from the OS level.

Your PHP upgrade is most likely affecting the crons in one of two ways:

1. The upgrade was large, like PHP5.6 to PHP7.0 and there's a deprecation warning somewhere (which will output in the crons' log) or the script is running some code that's now fully deprecated; most likely a query or a class/method named after a reserved word. Your logs will have more info, just make sure you have debugging turned on, otherwise your errors will be suppressed.
2. The new PHP settings from the upgrade have disabled some of the allowed rules from an older PHP version, such as getting away with empty or unassigned variables, and now your script is running into errors (ie. using a variable that doesn't exist, such as `$_REQUEST['something']`, which would have been empty but now returns an error that effects the rest of the script).

To fix this you *need* to know what the problem is. The easiest way is to access the log files that crons often create. If you don't get that with your host, ask them for it, or ask them to send you a copy of the error that's being created -- a quick Google on the error will tell you what the problem is. But without knowing more about the script or the error log, you probably won't get a better answer.

Comment: thank you all for your answer the upgrade was not too lagre its  from version 5.4 to 5.6.30 ,the script provider ask for a big money for his help!

Answer (score 0):

old command is working its just me i did copy past from my old backup and i forget the PHP at the firts off command ! nothing has changed the command should be like that exp : php /home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php